# How to sort a varchar datatype column by its numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a column in SQL Server that contains data like this:

```
1.1.1.QuestionText
1.1.1.Question
1.1.1(a).Questions
1.1.2.Questionswithtext
1.1.2(b).Text
10.1.1.Answers
2.1.1.Questions
2.2.2.QuestionText
```

How do I display this in ascending order?

Comment: If i understand you, you are trying to sort the text portion of the data?  While ignoring the numbers?  Are those values all in one field?

Comment: @paqogomez - I have to sort all the values(number and text) like first numbers to sort followed by characters.

Answer (score 1):

You *happen* to have a four-part naming, so you can use [`parsename()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx).  That results in something like this:

```
order by (case when isnumeric(arsename(col, 4)) = 1 then cast(parsename(col, 4) as int)
          end),
         (case when isnumeric(parsename(col, 3)) = 1 then cast(parsename(col, 3) as int)
          end),
         (case when isnumeric(parsename(col, 2)) = 1 then cast(parsename(col, 2) as int)
          end),
         (case when isnumeric(parsename(col, 1)) = 1 then cast(parsename(col, 1) as int)
          end),
         col
```

This isn't perfect, because you seem to have oddly placed parentheses.  But it might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Perhaps I've missed something, but [this produces a syntax error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9c96b/1)

Comment: Nice! I like the use of `Parsename()`, though I think it deserves a link to MSDN. I've edited your answer to include it, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT  name
FROM    ( SELECT    name, SUBSTRING(name, 1,
                              LEN(name) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(name)) + 1) n
          FROM      #tmp
        ) v
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(n, 4) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME(n, 3) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME(n, 2) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME(n, 1) AS INT)
```

Output:

```
name
1.1.1.QuestionText
1.1.1.Question
1.1.1(a).Questions
1.1.2.Questionswithtext
1.1.2(b).Text
2.1.1.Questions
2.2.2.QuestionText
10.1.1.Answers
```

If you want to order by text after version number then this will work:

```
SELECT  name
FROM    ( SELECT    name, SUBSTRING(name, 1,
                              LEN(name) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(name)) + 1) nv,
                          SUBSTRING(name, LEN(name) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(name)) + 2, 
                              LEN(name)) nt                            
          FROM      #tmp
        ) v
ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(nv, 4) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME(nv, 3) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME(nv, 2) AS INT),
         CAST(PARSENAME(nv, 1) AS INT),
         nt
```

Output:

```
name
1.1.1(a).Questions
1.1.1.Question
1.1.1.QuestionText
1.1.2(b).Text
1.1.2.Questionswithtext
2.1.1.Questions
2.2.2.QuestionText
10.1.1.Answers
```

Comment: I think your output should be different `1.1.1.QuestionText` will come after `1.1.1(a).Questions` ;).

Comment: May be it will be different on other machine. I am ordering only by version number and not by the text after it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        CREATE TABLE #TMP
        (
         name nvarchar(30)
        )

        INSERT INTO #TMP (name) VALUES ('1.1.1.QuestionText')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (name) VALUES ('1.1.1.Question')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (name) VALUES ('1.1.1(a).Questions')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (name) VALUES ('1.1.2.Questionswithtext')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (name) VALUES ('1.1.2(b).Text')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (name) VALUES ('10.1.1.Answers')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (name) VALUES ('2.1.1.Questions')
        INSERT INTO #TMP (name) VALUES ('2.2.2.QuestionText')

        select
        SUBSTRING(replace(name, '.',''),1,
                PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',  
                    replace(name, '.','')
                ) -1
            ) as replaced, name from #TMP order by 
        CAST( 
            SUBSTRING(replace(name, '.',''),1,
                PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',  
                    replace(name, '.','')
                ) -1
            )
        as int)
```

It works always when it starts from digits. It is ordered by this first digits only. If you want to order by digits first and rest of the text later you can change last query to (**I put in the select the same like in order by to show ordered parts**):

```
        select
        SUBSTRING(replace(name, '.',''),1,
                PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',  
                    replace(name, '.','')
                ) -1
            ) as replacedDigit,
            SUBSTRING(replace(name, '.',''),
                PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',  
                    replace(name, '.','')
                ), 100) as replacedText,

             name from #TMP order by 
        CAST( 
            SUBSTRING(replace(name, '.',''),1,
                PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',  
                    replace(name, '.','')
                ) -1
            )
        as int), SUBSTRING(replace(name, '.',''),
                PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',  
                    replace(name, '.','')
                ), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  *
FROM t
ORDER BY 
        CASE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 4)) 
            WHEN 0 THEN RIGHT('0000' + PARSENAME(name, 4), 4) 
            WHEN 1 THEN PARSENAME(name, 1)
            ELSE RIGHT('0000' + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(name, 2), 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)) - 1), 4) + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(name, 2), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)), LEN(name))
        END
    ,   CASE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 3)) 
            WHEN 0 THEN RIGHT('0000' + PARSENAME(name, 3), 4) 
            WHEN 1 THEN PARSENAME(name, 1)
            ELSE RIGHT('0000' + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(name, 2), 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)) - 1), 4) + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(name, 2), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)), LEN(name))
        END
    ,   CASE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)) 
            WHEN 0 THEN RIGHT('0000' + PARSENAME(name, 2), 4) 
            WHEN 1 THEN PARSENAME(name, 1)
            ELSE RIGHT('0000' + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(name, 2), 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)) - 1), 4) + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(name, 2), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)), LEN(name))
        END
    ,   CASE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 1)) 
            WHEN 0 THEN RIGHT('0000' + PARSENAME(name, 1), 4) 
            WHEN 1 THEN PARSENAME(name, 1)
            ELSE RIGHT('0000' + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(name, 2), 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)) - 1), 4) + SUBSTRING(PARSENAME(name, 2), PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', PARSENAME(name, 2)), LEN(name))
        END
```

For this:

```
1.1.1.Question
1.1.1.QuestionText
1.1.1(a).Questions
1.1.2.Questionswithtext
1.1.2(b).Text
2.1.1.Questions
2.2.2.QuestionText
10.1.1.Answers
```