# Comparing version string in sql

Tags: sql

I have a row in a table **APP** with record as

```
Version :1.1.120 ,category :Home , app:iphone
```

Now if the user sends an input as version 1.1.130 , would like to return the row details for version 1.1.120 , however for 1.1.115(lesser than the version in DB) wont return any row.

Also, if there is an additional record with detail as

```
Version :1.1.140 ,category :Books, app:iphone
```

Now if the input version is 1.1.145 I would like to run both the rows .Select sql with the version as input (present in the server is working) works ,but the above scenario is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to retrieve the current and previous version only?

Comment: Please add your DBMS tag - Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30426016/4519059 ;).

Comment: Also, what is the data type of the version column? I'm guessing varhcar...

Comment: Is version 1.1.13 higher or lower than 1.1.120?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: you are correct . it is varchar

Comment: @fyrye: yes only the current and previous versions only.

Comment: @jarlh: 1.1.13 higher than 1.1.120

Comment: @Amz if there is a record for 1.1.120, 1.1.13 and 1.1.140 and you enter 1.1.145 as input do you return all 3 of the ones in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just looking for a lower than in this situation:

```
SELECT *
FROM app
where version < '1.1.125';
SELECT *
FROM app
where version < '1.1.145';
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ddd0c/1)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.I will try out the same.

Answer (score 1):

Ok based on your specifications, if the record is greater than the maximum, then display current and previous versions, otherwise display versions that are not lesser than supplied input (Upgrades).

Show Upgrade Versions

```
SELECT * FROM app
WHERE 
CASE WHEN '1.1.120' > (SELECT MAX(version) FROM app)
THEN version <= '1.1.120'
ELSE version >= '1.1.120'
END
ORDER BY version DESC;
```

Show all previous versions

```
SELECT * FROM app
WHERE 
CASE WHEN '1.1.145' > (SELECT MAX(version) FROM app)
THEN version <= '1.1.145'
ELSE version >= '1.1.145'
END
ORDER BY version DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e26ad/3

I can filter this more to display ONLY the most recent upgrade instead of ALL upgrades, but was not clear as to what you were looking for should there be multiple records greater than the supplied version.